# Why they didn't change property directly in map() in Redux tutorial?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutability

a redux noob here.

In redux tutorial in [this part particularly](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#handling-additional-actions) Why they didn't do something like that

```js
        case 'todos/todoToggled': {
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: state.todos.map(todo => {
                    if (todo.id === action.payload.todoId) {
                        todo.completed = !todo.completed
                    }
                    return todo
                }
                )
            }
```

As far as I know `map()` doesn't have any side effects quoted from [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

Why they did this extra step?

```js
          // We've found the todo that has to change. Return a copy:
          return {
            ...todo,
            // Flip the completed flag
            completed: !todo.completed
          }
```

Will it affect the functionality? or they just want to be consistent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As far as I know `map()` doesn't have any side effects

It *can* have side-effects, that fact that the map method creates a new array doesn't mean it can't have any side effects. For example:

```js
const arr = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}];
const newA = arr.map(obj => {
  obj.x += 1; // changes the objects in `arr`
  return obj;
});
console.log(newA); // new array (objects are still references to original ones)
console.log(arr); // Also changed!
```

The map function gets passed a reference to each object, meaning that when you change `obj`, it also changes it within the original array. As a result, when you do:

```js
todo.completed = !todo.completed
```

you're changing the `todo` objects in your array, which results in you changing your state directly.

Unlike the above, the presented code:

```
{
  ...todo,
  completed: !todo.completed
}
```

does not change the `todo` object reference, but rather, it takes all the (enumerable own) keys from it and puts it in a new object, which also overwrites the `completed` key to hold the negated (ie: opposite) `completed` boolean value.

Comment: To make sure I understood you correctly. Did you mean that the argument of map callback is a reference to the object not a copy of it, right?

Comment: @AbdullahKhaled yes, that's correct, since the array contains objects, the argument passed to the callback will be a reference to the object, and not a copy