# Having trouble understanding why original object is affected after .map within example

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

I have been having trouble understanding why temp is being affected here. When looking at the console when running this code:

```
const objectsArray = [
    {'id': 1, 'name': 'Erik', 'yearsCompleted': 2, 'status': 'student'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'name': 'Carol', 'yearsCompleted': 1, 'status': 'student'}, 
    {'id': 3, 'name': 'Sarah', 'yearsCompleted': 4, 'status': 'student'}
];

temp = {
    actions: objectsArray.map(student => {
    if (student.yearsCompleted === 4) student.status = 'wow';
    return student
    })
}
console.log(temp)

temp2 = {
    actions: objectsArray.map(student => {
    if (student.yearsCompleted === 4) student.status = 'foo';
    return student
    })
}

console.log(temp)
console.log(temp2)
```

I end up getting the following result:

```
{ actions:
   [ { id: 1, name: 'Erik', yearsCompleted: 2, status: 'student' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Carol', yearsCompleted: 1, status: 'student' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Sarah', yearsCompleted: 4, status: 'wow' } ] }
{ actions:
   [ { id: 1, name: 'Erik', yearsCompleted: 2, status: 'student' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Carol', yearsCompleted: 1, status: 'student' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Sarah', yearsCompleted: 4, status: 'foo' } ] }
{ actions:
   [ { id: 1, name: 'Erik', yearsCompleted: 2, status: 'student' },
     { id: 2, name: 'Carol', yearsCompleted: 1, status: 'student' },
     { id: 3, name: 'Sarah', yearsCompleted: 4, status: 'foo' } ] }
```

Why is temp in this case being affected? Are we getting a reference to the objectsArray when setting the actions property of temp to the objectsArray.map function? I thought temp wouldn't be affected in this case. Thank you.

Comment: The `student` variable holds a reference to an object in  `objectsArray`, so when you change it with `student.status = 'foo'`,  you're changing the reference which is what `temp.actions` holds ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66654421/5648954) might help).

Comment: what is temp? how do you declare it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `student.status = 'foo'` changes the actual item in the `temp` array. You need to make a copy and return it using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)(`...`) as below.

```js
const objectsArray = [{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Erik',
    'yearsCompleted': 2,
    'status': 'student'
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Carol',
    'yearsCompleted': 1,
    'status': 'student'
  },
  {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Sarah',
    'yearsCompleted': 4,
    'status': 'student'
  }
];

temp = {
  actions: objectsArray.map(student => {
    if (student.yearsCompleted === 4) {
      return { ...student,
        status: 'wow'
      }
    };
    return student
  })
}
console.log(temp)

temp2 = {
  actions: objectsArray.map(student => {
    if (student.yearsCompleted === 4) {
      return { ...student,
        status: 'foo'
      }
    };
    return student
  })
}

console.log(temp)
console.log(temp2)
```